# Magento EE 1.14.2.0 Indexing Issue / Database Repair Tool failure "You have missed trigger(s)"

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-1.14, mysql-triggers, magento-catalog

Magento Details:

```
Magento EE 1.14.2.0
12 Websites 
80 Store Groups 
160 Stores
3500 Categories
15k products
75 Customer Groups
Mysql 5.5
php-fpm 5.6
```

My import process has always worked successfully prior to upgrade to 1.14

After import of new products and categories, I typically need to run a reindexing process for products to display.  I do this by running php shell/indexer.php --reindexall. This also included the add of new website with a new root category and product collection.

This process says it successfully completed, but I believe it must be failings. I've re-run this process numerous times with no success. I can get to direct product urls from new products. However, I cannot get to categories by url,  I can only get to them from controller route and pass category id.

In attempt to determine cause, I ran through Database repair tool process. However, I get the following errors and it does not appear to be correcting anything.

Below is the result of the script, which has me concerned.  Did I miss something on upgrade?

```
Repair Corrupted Database
You have missed trigger(s) "trg_catalog_category_entity_datetime_after_insert, trg_catalog_category_entity_datetime_after_update, trg_catalog_category_entity_datetime_after_delete" to table "catalog_category_entity_datetime"
You have missed trigger(s) "trg_catalog_category_entity_decimal_after_insert, trg_catalog_category_entity_decimal_after_update, trg_catalog_category_entity_decimal_after_delete" to table "catalog_category_entity_decimal"
You have missed trigger(s) "trg_catalog_category_entity_int_after_insert, trg_catalog_category_entity_int_after_update, trg_catalog_category_entity_int_after_delete" to table "catalog_category_entity_int"
You have missed trigger(s) "trg_catalog_category_entity_text_after_insert, trg_catalog_category_entity_text_after_update, trg_catalog_category_entity_text_after_delete" to table "catalog_category_entity_text"
You have missed trigger(s) "trg_catalog_category_entity_url_key_after_insert, trg_catalog_category_entity_url_key_after_update, trg_catalog_category_entity_url_key_after_delete" to table "catalog_category_entity_url_key"
You have missed trigger(s) "trg_catalog_category_entity_varchar_after_insert, trg_catalog_category_entity_varchar_after_update, trg_catalog_category_entity_varchar_after_delete" to table "catalog_category_entity_varchar"
You have missed trigger(s) "trg_catalog_product_bundle_selection_after_insert, trg_catalog_product_bundle_selection_after_update, trg_catalog_product_bundle_selection_after_delete" to table "catalog_product_bundle_selection"
You have missed trigger(s) "trg_catalog_product_entity_after_insert, trg_catalog_product_entity_after_update, trg_catalog_product_entity_after_delete" to table "catalog_product_entity"
You have missed trigger(s) "trg_catalog_product_entity_datetime_after_insert, trg_catalog_product_entity_datetime_after_update, trg_catalog_product_entity_datetime_after_delete" to table "catalog_product_entity_datetime"
You have missed trigger(s) "trg_catalog_product_entity_decimal_after_insert, trg_catalog_product_entity_decimal_after_update, trg_catalog_product_entity_decimal_after_delete" to table "catalog_product_entity_decimal"
You have missed trigger(s) "trg_catalog_product_entity_int_after_insert, trg_catalog_product_entity_int_after_update, trg_catalog_product_entity_int_after_delete" to table "catalog_product_entity_int"
You have missed trigger(s) "trg_catalog_product_entity_text_after_insert, trg_catalog_product_entity_text_after_update, trg_catalog_product_entity_text_after_delete" to table "catalog_product_entity_text"
You have missed trigger(s) "trg_catalog_product_entity_url_key_after_insert, trg_catalog_product_entity_url_key_after_update, trg_catalog_product_entity_url_key_after_delete" to table "catalog_product_entity_url_key"
You have missed trigger(s) "trg_catalog_product_entity_varchar_after_insert, trg_catalog_product_entity_varchar_after_update, trg_catalog_product_entity_varchar_after_delete" to table "catalog_product_entity_varchar"
You have missed trigger(s) "trg_catalog_product_link_after_insert, trg_catalog_product_link_after_update, trg_catalog_product_link_after_delete" to table "catalog_product_link"
You have missed trigger(s) "trg_catalog_product_super_link_after_insert, trg_catalog_product_super_link_after_update, trg_catalog_product_super_link_after_delete" to table "catalog_product_super_link"
You have missed trigger(s) "trg_catalogrule_product_price_after_insert, trg_catalogrule_product_price_after_update, trg_catalogrule_product_price_after_delete" to table "catalogrule_product_price"
You have missed trigger(s) "trg_core_config_data_after_insert, trg_core_config_data_after_update, trg_core_config_data_after_delete" to table "core_config_data"
You have missed trigger(s) "trg_core_store_after_insert, trg_core_store_after_delete" to table "core_store"
You have missed trigger(s) "trg_core_store_group_after_insert, trg_core_store_group_after_update, trg_core_store_group_after_delete" to table "core_store_group"
You have missed trigger(s) "trg_core_website_after_delete" to table "core_website"
You have missed trigger(s) "trg_customer_group_after_insert" to table "customer_group"
You have missed trigger(s) "trg_enterprise_url_rewrite_redirect_after_insert, trg_enterprise_url_rewrite_redirect_after_update, trg_enterprise_url_rewrite_redirect_after_delete" to table "enterprise_url_rewrite_redirect"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I don't know where to begin?  As running a reindex takes hours to complete I don't have much time to complete project.

Thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: Sometimes triggers can get lost, because of the definer, if you can get a copy of a stock 1.14 EE install and run `mysqldump -u -p -n -d -t --skip-opt --no-create-info --triggers database | sed -e 's/DEFINER=[^*]*\*/\*/' > triggers.sql` you can get a dump of all triggers you can apply

Comment: Yes, I figured out a hacked way to do that :20 mins ago... But much cleaner.... This corrected these errors... but indexing is still failing. So I'm back at a loss

Comment: How are you importing your products? And do you have the cron task setup to use `cron.sh` and set to run indefinitely? http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_install.html#install-cron

Comment: I'm doing indexing with update on save and no cron .  These products were imported with magmi.